# Trouble with Rest API using Curl in PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I'm trying to use the REST API of a telecommunications company to return an access token using curl, here is my code:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.touch.technology/auth/token",
  CURLOPT_POST=> true,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=*********&client_secret=*********",
  "content-type: x-www-form-urlencoded",
]);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($data);

?>
```

Yet all i recive is "string(12) "Unauthorized""

Can anybody tell me where im going wrong?

:[API Docs](https://api.touch.technology/docs/)

Comment: `"content-type: x-www-form-urlencoded"` isn't a valid setopt option.

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps, check the comments for explanation

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.touch.technology/auth/token",
  CURLOPT_POST=> true,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  //you have CURLOPT_POST set to true so don't need this
  //CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", 
  //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=*********&client_secret=*********",
  //don't need this
  //"content-type: x-www-form-urlencoded",
  //client secret and client_id must be url encoded
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=".urlencode(*********)."&client_secret=".urlencode(*********)
]);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($data);

?>
```

you can try to use [www.hurlit.com](http://www.hurlit.com) to test the API and make sure it works with the data you have (secret and key) and then try it out with curl.

Comment: It's easier to use `http_build_query()` for the postfields

Comment: its true http_build_query() is easier @Phil thanks for the edit

Comment: @KaleshwarChand thank you for your answer however this returns another error:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + string in C:\xampp\htdocs\MEMS\admin.php:19 Stack trace: #0

Comment: @Natan Rawlingson I have edited the code and it should work now I used "+" but it should have been "." sorry, confused js with php